# How to convert date into corresponding days

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a problem about a query.I don't know how to convert date into corresponding days.I have this query

```
SELECT A.DELIVERY_DATE,B.PO_DATE
 FROM t_mms_po_items A,t_mms_purchase_order B
 WHERE A.PO_ID = B.PO_ID AND A.ITEM_ID =165104
```

when I run this query it shows

```
`  DELIVERY_DATE  PO_DATE
 1  22-Oct-14    19-Aug-11
 2  11-Oct-14    12-Apr-11
 3  11-Oct-14    21-Apr-14
 4  22-Oct-14    22-Aug-14
```

But I want this in total days, such as 63 days, 90 days or something like that.What should I do? How can I convert date into days?Please help me to sort out.

Comment: Means you want difference between `DELIVERY_DATE`  and `PO_DATE` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just try subtracting the two date columns like this,

```
Select (A.DELIVERY_DATE - B.PO_DATE) no_of_days FROM ______ ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this code block for your problem

`select a.delivery_date
       ,b.po_date
       ,(a.delivery_date - b.po_date) as days
  from t_mms_po_items       a
      ,t_mms_purchase_order b
 where a.po_id = b.po_id
   and a.item_id = 165104`

Its gives you

`DELIVERY_DATE  PO_DATE    DAYS
 1  22-Oct-14    19-Aug-11  1160
 2  11-Oct-14    12-Apr-11  1278
 3  11-Oct-14    21-Apr-14  173
 4  22-Oct-14    22-Aug-14  61`

Answer (score -1):

Use below query

```
SELECT A.DELIVERY_DATE,B.PO_DATE, datediff(day,A.DELIVERY_DATE,B.PO_DATE) as days
 FROM t_mms_po_items A,t_mms_purchase_order B
 WHERE A.PO_ID = B.PO_ID AND A.ITEM_ID =165104
```

Comment: There is no `datediff()` in Oracle